# Is the stage perform operation of Nexus 3 atomic?

Tags: nexus

We are using Sonatype Nexus 3 Pro in our company. Or current product is a huge monolith consisting of a lot of maven artifacts (> 1000).

I am considering to use the staging feature of Nexus to push all these artifacts at once from one repository to another (within the same blobstore).

This should be a pure data base procedure. As data bases utilize the acid (atomicity, consistency, isolation and durability) principle, I would assume that pushing all my artifacts from registry A to registry B would do the same. So if any error occurs during this process (which takes a couple of minutes), all artifacts would still be in registry A afterwards.

I can not find anything about that in the documentation. Are my assumptions correct?